# logo dimensions not effective in 1.9.1 e-mail

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, email-templates

I uploaded a png logo with size 400x188px like this: 
`Admin panel -> Design -> I selected default config -> transactional emails`

After that I selected the logo -> upload, I set width 200 and height 94 and then saved the configuration.

Now when I create an order I receive the email with the logo, but it is still large. Do i need to change the header file for emails?

2nd issue i have is that when i select password forgotten option, i get the default magento logo.

I have flushed all cache (even that it is not active at the moment) etc.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You upload it correctly

To change this globally, go to:

> System > Configuration > General > Design > Transactional Emails

and upload it there. I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

You Should have an image in your folder called `logo_email.gif` same as `logo_print.gif` for the "Print View" pages.

So:

"/public_html/skin/frontend/fortis/default/images/logo_email.gif"

**I would recommend though using the image already in the size you need it instead of changing it through css and the Magento backend.**

Comment: Magento recommends to upload a double size image in pixels and specify the desired size in the configuration. Then the image looks good on new high resolution displays.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get mails with a wrong logo, look in your mail program for View raw HTML message, then you can see which logo it uses. Then simply replace that logo by your own logo. This even works for mails already sent. When your customers reopen the mail, the mail program will re-fetch the image.
This also works if you see question marks in the mail.
I had the same problem. The displayed logo in the password mail was in:
skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo_email.gif
It should be about 1200 px to fill the page width when printing an e-mail.
And you are right that it does not help to set the correct dimensions in the configuration. They are not used in this mail. Seems a bug to me.